# How to store duplicate data from xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having an xml file like

```
<Root>
 <Child val1="1" Val2="0"/>
 <Child val1="1" Val2="2"/>
 <Child val1="1" Val2="3"/>
 <Child val1="1" Val2="4"/>
 <Child val1="1" Val2="5"/>
 <Child val1="6" Val2="0"/>
 <Child val1="7" Val2="0"/>
</Root>
```

i need to store the data in any temporary storage ( namely a `Dictionary`) for some sort of manipulations . but i cannot use `dictionary` here because dictionary does not support same keys. can any one suggest me a better way to store this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` - or for storage only (no changes) you could use LINQ's [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) method which will build a multi-valued map for you very easily. Something like (using LINQ to XML):

```
var lookup = doc.Descendants("Child")
                .ToLookup(x => (int) x.Attribute("val1"),
                          x => (int) x.Attribute("val2"));

// Will iterate 5 times, printing 0, 2, 3, 4, 5 
foreach (var value in lookup[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine(value); 
}
```

EDIT: To display *all* the information, you'd do something like:

```
foreach (var grouping in lookup)
{
    foreach (var value in grouping)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", grouping.Key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : How do i get the value of val2(4th element where `val1` value is `1` and `val2` value is `4`) if i use LookUp . Can u please explain with sample code –

Comment: @Pramodh: Well, I've added a bit more information - but it's not clear whether that's exactly what you'll want.

Answer (score 1):

If .NET 4.0 you can use a [Tuple<int, int>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) and List<Tuple<int, int>> if data is not key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

you can still use a dictionary for the val1 values, just have the second value be a list of values instead of just a list.  then simply check if the DataKey exists, if it does do a list.Add(val2)